# Dynamically display relevant form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is a group of *questions* (hidden by default except the first one) with *yes|no buttons*

```
<div id="email" class="form-item">
        <h2>Q with 1 more option?</h2>
    <input type="button" value="true" data-value="web" />
    <input type="button" value="no" />
</div>
<div id="web" class="form-item">
        <h2>Q with 2 more option?</h2>
    <input type="button" value="yes" data-value="analy,seo" />
    <input type="button" value="no" />
</div>
<div id="analy" class="form-item">
        <h2>Q3?</h2>
    <input type="button" value="yes" data-value="qwe" />
    <input type="button" value="no" />
</div>
<div id="seo" class="form-item">
        <h2>Q4?</h2>
    <input type="button" value="yes" data-value="asd" />
    <input type="button" value="no" />
</div>
```

and the script to reveal the next relevant question (or multiple questions):

```
$('.form-item:nth-child(1)').slideDown('fast');

$('input[value="yes"],input[value="true"]').click(function () {
    next_id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    matches = [next_id];
    rx = /[^a-z|^0-9]/g;
    if (patt = next_id.match(rx)) {
        matches = next_id.split(patt[0]);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (matches[i]) {
        $('#' + matches[i]).slideDown('fast');
        i++;
    }
});
```

Sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/pu53rx31/

**There is any way to simplify this code?**

Comment: Why introduce the complication of a regular expression? Why not simply have `matches = next_id.split(',')`?

Comment: @76484 because in my case i can use any other isolation character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Comments:

The idea of splitting your `data-value`s with different isolation characters seems silly, just using a comma seems much better, as [@76484](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62111/76484) suggested, and removing the Regular Expression altogether.

However stepping around that, I can see a few things you could fix up:

### Yes and No buttons:

You use `yes` and `no` for testing the input, why not use `true` and `false`, that way instead of `$('input[value="yes"],input[value="true"]')`, you can just use `$('input[value]')`.

```
<input type="button" value="true" data-value="foo" />
<input type="button" value="false" />
```

### Regular Expression declaration:

Assuming entire removal of the regular expression isn't possible: you only use `rx` once, meaning you can just place the expression in the loop:

```
if (patt = next_id.match(/[^a-z|^0-9]/g)) {
```

### While loops:

`while` loops are notorious for causing recursion to occur, so you ought to replace it with a `for` loop.

It also removes the need for two extra lines for `declaring` the variable and `incrementing` the variable.

```
for (var i = 0; matches[i]; i++) {
  $('#' + matches[i]).slideDown('fast');
}
```